# How to inject SELinux policies permanently in android?

Tags: android, linux, filesystems, selinux, root-access

I have a rooted android device and I need to inject following policies into it:

```
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p transition -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p rlimitinh -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p siginh -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p read -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p execute -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t shell_exec -c file -p getattr  -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t vendor_toolbox_exec -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
sepolicy-inject -s init -t su -c process -p noatsecure -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p getattr -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p execute -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p execute_no_trans -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c dir -p search -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t storage_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t tmpfs -c dir -p search -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c dir -p search -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t mnt_user_file -c lnk_file -p read -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c dir -p search -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p append -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p read -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t toolbox_exec -c file -p open -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p read -l
sepolicy-inject -s su -t sdcardfs -c file -p write -l
```

As you can see, I am using `sepolicy-inject` commands to inject the required policies. I am facing a problem where on reboot these policies not exists anymore.

As per my understanding the new policies are injected at `/sys/fs/selinux/policy` location and this is not persistent storage. Also, there is a file on root partition `/sepolicy` which contain these policy rules.

I found `./sepolicy` in `boot.img`. I have a A/B partition device so, the `./sepolicy` in `boot.img` is for recovery only.

Now, I am not able to understand how to inject the required policies permanently to the device because of following reason:

1. `/sys/fs/selinux/policy` and `/sepolicy` are not on permanent storage partition.
2. `boot.img` only contain SELinux policies that are available on recovery only.

Please suggest how can I achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was asked quite some time ago, but since I tried doing something similar recently and this post was one of the top hits on Google, I want to share my recent experience to help others.

As I believe the answer answer your questions, here is a shameless copy/paste of my answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215010/how-to-make-selinux-injected-rules-persistent-without-unpacking-packing-boot-img):

*Note that this answer will focus solely on Android 9 to 13 and Treble devices.*

If we want to know how to modify the SELinux policies, I believe it is good to first understand how the policies are loaded in the first place.

**SELinux in the boot process**

At an early stage of the Android boot process and after mounting most of the partitions, `init` will attempt to load the SELinux policies from a monolithic sepolicy file found at either `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`. If `init` notices that the device is updated out of sync, `init` will instead recompile the SELinux policies based on `.cil` files that can be found on several locations.

You can find all the details in the comments of the [init/selinux.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/android11-release/init/selinux.cpp) source file and by looking at the implementation, but here is a summary of the exact steps taken by `init`:

1. Find the sepolicy file to use:

   - if `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` exists, use it as the sepolicy file to use
   - else, if `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` exists, use it as the sepolicy file to use
   - else if neither of the above exists, stop here, recompile the policies based on the `.cil` files and load the newly compiled sepolicy file.
2. Check if device was updated out of sync:

   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/system/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.system_ext_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/system_ext/etc/selinux/system_ext_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.product_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256` and `/product/etc/selinux/product_sepolicy_and_mapping.sha256`
   - (On Android 13) Compare `/(odm|vendor)/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy.apex_sepolicy.sha256` and `/dev/selinux/apex_sepolicy.sha256`
   - if any of the above pair of files do not match, stop here, recompile the policies based on the `.cil` files and load the newly compiled sepolicy file.
3. If everything is ok, load the precompiled sepolicy file (`/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy`)

The compilation of the policies based on the `.cil` files is as follows:

1. Get the latest version of the policies that are compatible with the `vendor` version (`/vendor/etc/selinux/plat_sepolicy_vers.txt`, note that `init` does not look at the file in the `/odm` partition)
2. Gather the `.cil` files to compile:

   - `/system/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/system/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.compat.cil`
   - `/system_ext/etc/selinux/system_ext_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/system_ext/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/product/etc/selinux/product_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/product/etc/selinux/mapping/{vendor_version}.cil`
   - `/vendor/etc/selinux/plat_pub_versioned.cil`
   - `/vendor/etc/selinux/vendor_sepolicy.cil` or if it does not exist: `/vendor/etc/selinux/nonplat_sepolicy.cil`
   - `/odm/etc/selinux/odm_sepolicy.cil`
3. Compile the above files with `secilc` to `/dev/sepolicy.XXXXXX`
4. Load policies from `/dev/sepolicy.XXXXXX`

**Modifying SELinux policies permantently**

Now that we understand how `init` loads the policies, it is easy to see how one could permanently add new policies to the system:

- Directly add the policies to `/odm/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` or `/vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy` with `sepolicy-inject`:

  ```
  sepolicy-inject -s su -t system_file -c file -p entrypoint -P /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy -o /vendor/etc/selinux/precompiled_sepolicy
  ```
- Make `init` thinks the device is updated out of sync (By modifying one of the above `.sha256` files, or deleting the precompiled sepolicy files) and modify one of the above `.cil` files

Note that in both cases, you will need to have a read-write access to the partition you want to modify (`/vendor`, `/odm`, and/or `/system`). These partitions are normally mounted as read-only, so you will have to either:

- Remount them as read-write if you have root access (either because your device is rooted, or using `adb root` on a `userdebug` Android build)
- Boot in recovery mode, mount the partitions as read-write and modify them in recovery

  - [This update-package template](https://github.com/Alhyoss/android-flashable-zip) I made may interest you there

If you do not want to have to remount the partitions every time you want to change the SELinux policies, you can add some SELinux rules to allow `init` to load new policies, and then create an `init` script that will load new policies. You can find which SELinux rules are needed by searching for SELinux violations (avc errors) in the device logs on startup:

```
adb logcat | grep avc
```

With this, you will be able to have an `init` script that loads new policies with `sepolicy-inject`.

Answer (score 0):

"/sepolicy" is a ramdisk so it's temporarily. You can solve it by put that command in some "init" script that will run "sepolicy-inject ..." commands at bootup ;)

Comment: "/sepolicy" is temporary ramdisk **only on pre-[system-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root) devices**.

Comment: This is not working. I got `avc: denied` errors because of missing SE-Linux policies to run these commands as root.

Comment: Please refer https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215010/how-to-make-selinux-injected-rules-persistent-without-unpacking-packing-boot-img/215395#215395 for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

just disable selinux by setting it to permissive